# How to form a string with parts of dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sqldatetime

I have datetimes in a table, in this manner (two in each row in a table):

```
Row 1: 2012-06-31 01:00:00
Row 2: 2012-06-31 02:00:00
Row 3: 2012-06-31 03:00:00
Row 4: 2012-06-31 04:00:00
...
```

And I want to get each hour as an interval, to get it from a report:

```
For the first row:  From 1 to 2
For the second row: From 2 to 3
...
For each row: 'From [hour(date)] to [hour(date)+1]'
```

But I don't stop getting "conversion error" with every combination con CONVERT, CAST, DATEPART or DATEADD.

I am new in dealing this kind of issues with SQL... How would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Use DatEPART Function with CAST

```
declare @dte datetime='2012-01-01 05:02:00'
select  'From '+ cast (DATEPART(HH,@dte) as char(2))+
             'to ' +cast(  DATEPART(HH,@dte)+1 as char(2))
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4099)

EDIT:

IF you want to retrieve from a table

```
declare @t table(dte datetime);
insert into @t values('2012-01-01 05:02:00');
insert into @t values('2012-01-01 06:02:00');
 
select  'From '+ cast (DATEPART(HH,dte) as char(2))+
             'to ' +cast(  DATEPART(HH,dte)+1 as char(2))
             from @t
```

Comment: That works great, but i need to do it getting the datetime from a table. Something like "select id, 'From' + cast (DATEPART(HH,franja) as char(2)) + ... from @tabla_franjas"

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
 Select 'From ' + Convert(varchar(2),datepart(hour,dateColumn)) 
  + ' to ' + convert(varchar(2),datepart(hour,dateColumn)+1)
 from Sample
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1875/1)

Comment: It looks great but i can't get it working :S "Error converting data type from varchar to int.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select 'From '+RIGHT(dtColumn,len(dtColumn)-charindex(' ',dtColumn,1)) + ' To '+convert(varchar(8),dateadd(hh,1,convert(time,RIGHT(dtColumn,len(dtColumn)-charindex(' ',dtColumn,1))))) from yourtable
```